# AS3 Constrain an mc's startdrag to a rectangle with both registration points at center

Tags: actionscript-3

Cannot figure this one out. How do i constrain the drag of an mc whose registration point is in the center to a larger clip whose registration point is also in the center? The code below drags the clip named img, but doesn't constrain to the 'rect' clip.

```
var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(rect.width/2-img.width/2, rect.height/2-img.height/2, rect.width-img.width, rect.height-img.height);

img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
img.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);

function drag(event:MouseEvent) {
    img.startDrag(false, bounds);
}
function drop(event:MouseEvent) {
    img.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rect` is the rectangle you want your object (`img`) to stay inside of, and they are both anchored in the center, then this is what you need:

```
var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle();
bounds.x = rect.x + (img.width * .5) - (rect.width * .5);  //offset by + half of the image, and - half of the rectangle
bounds.y = rect.y + (img.height * .5) - (rect.height * .5);
bounds.width = rect.width - img.width; //make the bounds the size of the rectangle, minus the size of the image
bounds.height = rect.height - img.height;
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work; 'img' snaps to the bottom right corner of 'rect' on start drag. Keep in mind that both the rect & the img clip both have their registration points at the center.

Comment: Ok, was only assuming the `img` was center.  try the updated code

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly! Thanks. My apologies for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

registration points have nothing to do with the drag bounding box.

for example

```
new Rectangle(0,0,100,100)
```

Will only allow the MovieCLip to only move from 0,0 to 100,100 top left most corner of the stage.

[EDIT]

```
boundingBox.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
boundingBox.graphics.beginFill(0);
boundingBox.graphics.lineTo(400,0);
boundingBox.graphics.lineTo(400,400);
boundingBox.graphics.lineTo(0,400);
boundingBox.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
boundingBox.graphics.endFill();
boundingBox.x = 100;
boundingBox.y = 100;


dragTarget.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
dragTarget.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
dragTarget.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
dragTarget.graphics.endFill();
dragTarget.x = 150;
dragTarget.y = 150;

container.addChild(boundingBox) 
container.addChild(dragTarget) 
this.addChild(container)

dragTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onDown)


var boundingBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
var dragTarget:Sprite = new Sprite();
var container:Sprite = new Sprite()
function onDown(event:Event):void{
  var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(boundingBox.x,
                 boundingBox.y,
                 boundingBox.width-dragTarget.width,
                 boundingBox.height-dragTarget.height)
  dragTarget.startDrag( false,bounds )
}
```

Comment: How do i set the bounding box rectangle based on the size & position of the 'rect' clip, so the img clip wont appear outside it?